# How to record audio input using x-webkit-speech?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webkit, audio-recording

I wanna record the audio input, save it as a wave file and stream it to server, could it possible using x-webkit-speech ? If not, how can I realize this?

Comment: I too would like to know if this is possible. I want to take the audio recording and send it to my own speech recognition server, rather than Google's.

Comment: This link introduce couple ways to solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554982/how-to-record-voice-in-a-browser